# Oozie workflow - Pass parameters from Java action to hive using Hue console

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie, hue

I have two actions in workflow.xml file 
1. Java action to find variables like current date, hour etc. and it has `<capture-output/>` tag in it.
the output of my first action under stdout logs on Hue console is like:

```
Oozie Launcher, capturing output data:
  =======================
  #Tue Apr 25 13:14:47 EDT 2017
  TODAY=2017-04-25
  LH_HOUR=12
  MONTH=04
  LH_DAY=2017-04-25


  =======================

  Oozie Launcher, uploading action data to HDFS sequence file: hdfs://mas/user/hdfs/oozie-oozi/0001690-170424220032457-oozie-oozi-W/java-b5aa--java/action-data.seq

  Oozie Launcher ends
```

Second action is hive query where we have two parameters in query

```
select * from table where day = ${LH_DAY} and hour=${LH_HOUR}
```

Please suggest how can i pass the output values of first action as parameters to second action (hive)
I have given two parameters in parameters:

```
LH_DAY=${LH_DAY}
LH_HOUR=${LH_HOUR}
```

When i am running my workflow then i am getting a popup to pass the values of LH_DAY and LH_HOUR.
I want to pass the values that are output from first Java action i.e

```
LH_DAY=2017-04-25
LH_HOUR=12
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: @Dudu Markovitz Please help

Comment: **RTFM** - instantiate `LH_DAY` with `${wf:actionData("Java-action-name-here")["LH_DAY"]}` cf. https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.2.6_Hadoop_Jobs_EL_Function

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thank you for the response
 
Where do we need to initiate LH_DAY and LH_HOUR? This is the configuration that we have in workflow.xml 
<script>process.hql</script> <param>LH_DAY=${wf:actionData('capture-date')['LH_DAY']}<‌​/param> <param>LH_HOUR=${wf:actionData('capture-date')['LH_HOUR']}</‌​param>

Comment: Java EL is supposed to accept either single or double quotes for string literals, so yes, it should work.